# How to pass Select Values to React Form when Select is in a Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, select, components

I'm working on a React application with Typescript. I created a multi-step form. Each form page is it's own component, and fields are separate components. I'm able to view data from Text Fields onSubmit, however, I can't figure out how to do the same with the Select field as that component has its own onChange attribute.

These are snippets from the Main Form. Fields have been changed. Let's pretend "State" is a dropdown:

```
type FormData = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  state: string;
};

const INITIAL_DATA: FormData = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  state: "",
};
```

Hook to get User Data

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA);

  function updateFields(fields: Partial<FormData>) {
    setData((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, ...fields };
    });
  }
```

This is how I'm getting all of the steps. NOTE: I cleaned up irrelevant code. This focuses on just the parts that get data:

```
function getStepsContent(step: number) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <Personal
            {...data}
            updateFields={updateFields}
          />
        );
      case 1:
        return (
          <Address
            {...data}
            updateFields={updateFields}
          />
        );
      default:
        return (
          <Personal
            {...data}
            updateFields={updateFields}
          />
        );
    }
  }
```

On the Personal Form Page, I have:

```
type PersonalData = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  state: string;
}

type PersonalProps = PersonalData & {
  updateFields: (fields: Partial<PersonalData>) => void
}
```

This is an example of the form field. Note: This is where I'm pulling in a custom field components. StyledTextField (uses MUI textfield) pulls in data, the StyledSelectField (uses MUI select field) does not:

```
<StyledTextField 
  label="First Name"  
  name="firstName"
  value={firstName}
  onChange={e => updateFields({firstName: e.target.value})}
/>

<StyledSelect
  label="State"
  placeholder="Select One"
  name="state"
  data={state}
  onChange={e => updateFields({state: e.target.value})}
/>
```

This is my Select Component. It does grab the data, but it doesn't push it through to the form when submitted:

```
interface IData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface StyledSelectProps {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  name: string;
  onChange?: (event: SelectChangeEvent) => void;
  data: IData[];
}

export default function StyledSelect({
  id,
  label,
  placeholder,
  name,
  onChange,
  data,
}: StyledSelectProps) {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);

  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={id}>
          {label}
        </InputLabel>

        <Select
          id={id}
          value={value}
          label={id}
          name={name}
          variant="standard"
          defaultValue=""
          renderValue={value !== "" ? undefined : () => placeholder}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {data.map(({ id, name }) => (
            <MenuItem key={id} value={name}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think the main issue is that I have an onChange on the Select, but also need to do an onChange on the single Form Page. Also, because I have values coming through here via useState, I'm not able to call it in on the single Form Page.

Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your StyledSelect you should call the onChange from props to get you fn `updateFields` called. Update the handleChange fn in StyledSelect component with the following:

```
const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    onChange(event)
};
```

Comment: I'm trying the same approach for when it's an MUI slider but I'm getting the following error: 

Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>'.

Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'Event & { target: { value: string; name: string; }; }'.

The function looks like this: 

const handleSliderChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[], activeThumb: number) => {
    if (typeof newValue === "number") {
      setValue(newValue);
      onChange(event)
    }
  };

Should I be passing something other than "event" on onChange(event)?

Comment: I should add, it does work, but I still get the error message. If I close out of the error message, I can see the value passing through perfectly when the form is submitted.

Comment: The error says it is expecting a string in SelectChangeEvent, so you can pass directly the newValue on onChange => onChange(newValue) but remember to update your onChange prop on StyleSelect<StyledSelect
  label="State"
  placeholder="Select One"
  name="state"
  data={state}
  onChange={updateFields}
/>

Comment: This gives me an error on both sides. With ```onChange(newValue)``` I get an Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>'. on the StyledSelect, I get this error: Type '(fields: Partial<PhysicalToolsData>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SelectChangeEvent<string>) => void'. Types of parameters 'fields' and 'event' are incompatible. Type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<PhysicalToolsData>'. Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<PhysicalToolsData>'.